# How to create a file with some specific content using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, ubuntu, cat

In the middle of a shell script, I need to create a file with some specific content. How do I do it? Can it be done using `cat`?

Comment: What is this file you are trying to create and what should be its contents? Provide some more information!

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with `cat` and a here-document:

```
cat >outfilename <<END_FILE
this is the contents of the file

       la-di-da!

END_FILE
```

The here-document is what's between the `<<END_FILE` and the corresponding `END_FILE` at the end.  The ending `END_FILE` must be the only word on that line and must be placed at the start of the line.  The word `END_FILE` may be any word (e.g. `END_CONFIG_FILE` or `WHEN_WILL_SUMMER_COME` or whatever makes sense).

Variables will be expanded in the document.  If this is not wanted, then quote the first here-document delimitier:

```
cat >outputfilename <<'MY_DOC'
another here document thingy

     The $PATH variable will not be expanded here
MY_DOC
```

A here-document is technically a *redirection* and in the examples above we redirect it into the `cat` command.  The `cat` command the passes it on to the named file using a standard output redirection.

See also questions tagged with [here-document](/questions/tagged/here-document) on this site.

---

From comments: "I get *Permission denied* and `sudo` doesn't help"

Yes, if you don't have write permissions in the directory, you can't redirect to the output file. Also, the creation of the output file happens before `sudo` is even called, so using `sudo` won't help.

You could do

```
sudo tee outputfilename >/dev/null <<MY_DOC
contents of file
goes here
MY_DOC
```

This will run `tee` as root and `tee` will create `outputfilename` in the current directory (as root).  The redirection to `/dev/null` is to stop `tee` from also outputting the document to the terminal.

The `tee` command copies its input to all files named on its command line, and to the standard output (the terminal if not piped to another command).

Comment: The above command is returning the error -bash: outfilename: Permission denied. Tried sudo too

Comment: @SampadMund That's because you don't have permission to write in the current directory. Using `sudo` will not help since the redirection is not part of the command that `sudo` executes. Instead, use `sudo tee outputfilename >/dev/null <<MY_DOC` etc.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary (not necessarily text) content, you can use `uudecode`:

`````
uudecode << "EOF" | gunzip > some-file
begin 644 -
M'XL(``S*N%H``ZMW]7%C8F1D@`%F!CL&$.]"&(3O`!7W8&>"JW%@L&#@!)*R
M##(,;$`^*Y(Z=/H'(RK-`;>'@8$%B"V@QJ+3,@RH-",2S<J`&[QXPHA",S`H
MP/6!W#KA,T1\PF=%%+I""**Z0)4!11\35-^-OQ!]-_XJHM`?H-9\0/,?"Q2'
M0/V#3KLPH-(L4#K@:4D*B+U@/<1`=+H%:@&,AND+!.ICPP@-W$``2@=![<,5
M+@4\#"@T+%3U<S*3S$ST<U)T<S+S2BMT*RS,=,U,](KS]8S`;A*`JG7W"P6K
MAX6C`M3-(@R0-`"25^T\MOA2RP9MCB/-5_Z?6'QD>\KV8D&@7`54'SL0+UOH
MP2'$N$Y>XXJ`\`H6A@D@N4H@K@+B&B"N`^(&(&X$XF8@;H6ZLQV(.Y'\W06E
MNX%X;T#9O->7W_,9'?DNM+/W(]^T!9W3;Q9&R.QZ/*GFO$YRT>09-FNW_6)\
M[=_WM][)]>H;RT_=,CYV2[F?)CE^9;*KC]Z\Z+M0?=:LTM[C#Q(T97MD&/``
C?Z"GA;"('V?"+OX1A[@'(W;Q<&;LXINAY@``J665NN@#````
`
end
EOF
`````

Where that output (in the sample above the first 1000 bytes of `/bin/ls` on my system) is generated with `gzip < file | uuencode -`.